# Get X, Y coordinates in the center of a raster cell

Tags: arcgis-10.0, python, python-2.6

I am trying to get the X, Y coordinates of all the cells of a raster file, using Python 2.6 and ArcGIS 10.0.

I would like to get the X, Y coordinates in the center of the cell.

Is there any way to do so?

Comment: the raster is equally spaced, so you just need to know the max X, min X, max Y, max Y and the raster resolution value.

Comment: Hasn't ESRI retained analogs of $$XMap and $$YMap in Python *yet*?  See [this forums post](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/3644-Generate-a-grid-of-latitude-values) for a discussion of the issue and an expeditious workaround.

Comment: Finally I tried the code of Marcin. It was really useful...

Answer (score 10):

You can use the arcpy module's [GetRasterProperties](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//0017000000m7000000) command to get the xmin, xmax, ymin and ymax coordinates for the raster. By converting these values, which are returned using `getOutput` as unicode, to floats simple arithmetic can be performed to give the center coordinates of the raster file.

```
import arcpy

path = r'C:\dem\profile-dtm_57583\grids\ns78ne1'

xmin = arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management(path,'LEFT')
xmax = arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management(path,'RIGHT')
ymin = arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management(path,'BOTTOM')
ymax = arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management(path,'TOP')

centerX = (float(xmax.getOutput(0)) + float(xmin.getOutput(0))) / 2
centerY = (float(ymax.getOutput(0)) + float(ymin.getOutput(0))) / 2

print centerX, centerY
```

**EDIT:**

To get the coordinates of every cell in the raster, you can take the raster cellsize, and use it as a step to iterate through all the values from xmin to xmax and ymin to ymax to get pass through the coordinates for each cell.

```
#assuming square cells
cellsize = arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management(path,'CELLSIZEX')
cellsize = int(cellsize.getOutput(0))

for x in xrange(int(xmin.getOutput(0)), int(xmax.getOutput(0)), cellsize):
    for y in xrange(int(ymin.getOutput(0)), int(ymax.getOutput(0)), cellsize):
        print x,y
```

**Note this code will take a long time to run with this print statement as it must print a new line for every cell in your raster.**

Another method for this would be to read the convert the raster to an ASCII raster and read it into a 2D numpy array. The array indexes would then correspond to the coordinates of the cells.

Comment: I have a 5x5 grid of cells. With the help of the above code we can get the X, Y coordinates location of the whole cell, but what if we need to get the X, Y coordinates of every cell?

Comment: I have updated the answer to give coordinated for each cell.

Comment: Would you please explain me how the 2D numpy array indexes correspond to the coordinates of the cells? I have created this numpy array for my raster file... and I have already read every cell value! Is there any extra command to read at the same time the coordinates of every cell? But I am also wondering whether I can obtain the coordinates in the center of every grid cell. I really thank you very much for your time!!!

Comment: To find the center of a cell simply add half the cell size to each x and y coordinate. The numpy array index will count from 0,0 but you can translate that index to your coordinate system by adding xmin, ymin to each index value.

Comment: But how can I get the numpy array index? and how can I obtain the X, Y coordinates from the index? i am a really new user in Python scripting... please excuse me for my really stupid queries...

Comment: You can access the index using nested for loops, as in the example code I provided above, which can iterate through every index value.

Answer (score 2):

If you convert the raster to points add the X,Y fields and then use the calculate geometry function to add values to the X and Y fields.

Comment: I am actually programming in Python language and I would like to do the former procedure in Python.

Comment: so maybe you could have a look at arcpy.RasterToPoint_conversion(), arcpy.AddFeild() and arcpy.UpdateCursor()